# How do I center this main element so that in landscape mode the element isn't cut off from the top?

Tags: html, css

The page in portrait looks good, but in landscape, the main element is cut off a bit at the top and only scrolls down.

This is the page in landscape mode.

[image: this is the page in landscape mode.]

Below is snippet of the CSS code for the body and main elements.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  width: 1440px;
  max-width: 1440px;
  font-family: 'Red Hat Display', sans-serif;
  font-size: 100%;
  background-color: hsl(225, 100%, 94%);
  background-image: url(/images/pattern-background-desktop.svg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 500px;
  height: 667px;
}
```

Comment: you need to post your HTML code too

Comment: Please edit your post and revise the snippet I created to show the problem.

Comment: Try removing the `top:50%` because you only want to center horizontally

Comment: @fxtrot when i do that it take the image out about half of the element and still hugs the top of the screen.

Comment: @DevAldo change `translate: (-50%, -50%)` to `translateX: (-50%)`

Answer (score 0):

The way to avoid this problem is to use [object-fit](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/css-cropping-images-object-fit) from CSS properties. You can use the [Mobile-Detect](https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect) JavaScript library to change the element's style sheet by detecting whether the mobile device is horizontal or vertical.

```js
if( $detect->isMobile() && !$detect->isTablet() )
{
    /* Apply style properties for mobile devices */

} elseif ( $detect->isTablet() ) {
    /* Apply style properties for tablet devices */

} else {
    /* Apply style properties for desktop devices */
}
```

Add the following style jQuery to the `<img>` element and/or other elements to crop the image and keep the aspect ratio:

```css
<img id="resizeImage" style="width: 300px; height: 400px; object-fit: scale-down;"/>
```

Comment: I am not really familiar with JavaScript as I am yet to start learning it. So I am looking for a solution based on CSS for now.